# Valid in FireFox Invalid in Chrome? background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(53, 53, 53), rgb(34, 34, 34));

Tags: css

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(53, 53, 53), rgb(34, 34, 34));
```

Why is this CSS property invalid in Chrome but Valid in Firefox? And any suggestions on how to make it valid in both browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses different code to render this into a background gradient.

You can find an example of the code [here](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the browser specific vendor prefixes.

I usually use a generator that will give you code for all browsers.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

WebKit updated to match the spec syntax, so you should have smth like this this to get maximum browser support:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#917c4d), to(#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
background: linear-gradient(#917c4d, #ffffff);
```